# jquery hover().addClass() problem

Tags: jquery, hover

http://jsfiddle.net/aBaw6/2/

This demo does not add class when you hover a list item.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover);
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

*html*

```
<ul>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Bread</li>
    <li>Chips</li>
    <li>Socks</li>
</ul>
```

*css*

```
.hover{
    color:green;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include code in the content of the question instead of only via a link. Thanks. EDIT: I updated your question for you. Notice the syntax highlighting in the javascript. It offers a pretty big clue that something's malformed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your JavaScript was badly formed:

```
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover);
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

Should be:

```
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  }
  );
```

If you click on the `JS Lint` button to the top of the screen it would've told you this (this isn't intended as a *criticism*, just a *note* for your future use of JS Fiddle).

Comment: And if you *had* we'd all be a little less-rewarded with rep; so no worries at all =)

Comment: I don't see **JS Lint** in JS Fiddle site? but there is **JSHints**, did they change it?

Comment: I hadn't noticed, to be honest, but it looks like they did, yeah. That, or I spectacularly misread the name. Either way is quite possible.

Answer (score 6):

Your javascript syntax is incorrect

```
$(this).addClass('hover);
```

Should be:

```
$(this).addClass('hover');
```

You forgot to terminate the string.

It works just fine with this change.

Answer (score 3):

While others noted the missing quotation mark, I'd note that you should really be doing this with CSS instead of javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/aBaw6/8/

```
li:hover{
    color:green;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

IE6 doesn't support this on a `<li>`, but you could wrap the content with an `<a>` and style that if support is needed.

If you did use javascript, you could reduce your code like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/aBaw6/7/

```
$("li").hover( function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover', e.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You Have Missed the quote '

```
   $("li").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
      },
      function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
      }
    );
```