# jQuery slide down div - disappears when over it

Tags: jquery

I have doing a slide down menu with options in the slide down.

I am using the following jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu_item").hover(function() {
        $(".menu_options").slideDown(400);
    }, function() {
        $(".menu_options").slideUp(400);
    });
});
```

The problem I have is that when it slides down and I go on to the div that has slid down it disappears - here is the screenshot of the set up

[image: Screenshot]

The HTML for this area is

```
<div class="menu">
            <div class="menu_item" id="1">
                Landlord Packages
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <div class="menu_item">
                Single Items
            </div>
            <div class="menu_options" id="1"></div>
        </div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help :-)

JSFiddle script http://jsfiddle.net/pCTXq/

Comment: can you include your css too? Or better yet, provide a jsFiddle with an example?

Comment: Same kind of topic other there :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085758/jquery-mousover-on-a-div-open-submenu-which-should-stay-open-when-mouseout/7085858#7085858

Good luck !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu_item, .menu_options").hover(function() {
        $(".menu_options").stop(true, true).slideDown(400);
    }, function() {
        $(".menu_options").stop(true, true).delay(10).slideUp(400);
    });
});
```

This should do what you need.

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MCvsd/54/

Edit: the fiddle you provided, updated: http://jsfiddle.net/pCTXq/1/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - That works great although the hover gradient that I have over .menu_item disappears as obviously I am not hovering over this - can this be fixed in jQuery - Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish that with `.addClass` and `.removeClass` This question addresses it -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358964/jquery-hover-addclass-problem

Comment: Thank you :-) that worked fine but am unsure where to remove the class - I have updated the JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pCTXq/2/

Comment: You need to add a CSS class called hover :)

Comment: Sorry I should have explained - I did that and it works fine except when I come off it the hover class still remains - when I put in the removeClass it takes me back to square one - I have a lot of jQuery learning to do ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your watching for a hover on `.menu_item` to slide `.menu_options` down, but since `.menu_options` is outside of `.menu_item`, moving the mouse to `.menu_options` is going to hide it.

You can solve this by nesting your `.menu_options` within each `.menu_item` div. It would be good to have a JSfiddle or codepen (with your css) to troubleshoot this.

```
<div class="menu">

  <div class="menu_item" id="1">
      Landlord Packages
  </div>

  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div class="menu_item">
      Single Items
     <div class="menu_options" id="1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested is the way but if you still donot want to use nested, You can do something as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu_item").hover(function() {
        $(".menu_options").slideDown(400);
    });
    $(".menu_options").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".menu_options").slideUp(400);
    });
});
```