# Hover in and out moving too fast, slidedown get error

Tags: jquery

Hover in and out `.logo` moving too fast, will get error,  the div `.nav_b` not show again.
but it's weird if demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4yX2/) is fine..

I can't seem how to fix it, I also tried use `animate` like the code below, so any help will be appreciated, Thanks...

```
$('.logo').hover(function(){
    $('.nav_b').slideDown({duration: 200, queue: false});

    // $('.nav_b').animate({height: 'show', width:'hide', easing:'swing'}, {duration : 200, queue: false});     
},function(){
    $('.nav_b').slideUp({duration: 200, queue: false});

    // $('.nav_b').animate({height: 'hide', width:'hide', easing:'swing'}, {duration : 200, queue: false});
});
```

Comment: Could you write it in more english friendly language? I'm not good too but my questions are understandable for others.

Comment: @PSL if in chrome jsfiddle both ok..

Comment: @vibskov nopes your fiddle fails for me Chrome after quick hovers, it never comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably could be because of your pending slideAnimations. Use stop() to stop any pending animation before slideTrasitions.

#### [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
  $(function(){
    $('.logo').hover(function(){
        $('.nav_b').stop().slideDown({duration: 200, queue: false});
        // $('.nav_b').animate({height: 'show', width:'show', easing:'swing'}, {duration : 200, queue: false});     
    },function(){
        $('.nav_b').stop().slideUp({duration: 200, queue: false});
        // $('.nav_b').animate({height: 'hide', width:'hide', easing:'swing'}, {duration : 200, queue: false});
    });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhkZN/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, the div `.search` is ok now but the wrap `.nav_b` still missing like http://imgur.com/Sh2azXw

Comment: @vibskov what do you mean by `wrap nav_b still missing`

Comment: please check imgur.com/Sh2azXw  after quick move, the `.nav_b` not show just like this img, only `.search`

Comment: @vibskov See my edit. it shows like that picture only... WHats the issue?

Comment: @vibskov Oh i got what you are asking. It has nothing to do with animation . You need to fix your css. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HAJSx/. Without animation, it appears the same.

Comment: yes if in jsfiddle is what i want, but I use it test in mamp safari chrome, still like imgur.com/Sh2azXw after move fast can't see .nav_b

Comment: I don't know why but after I see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16171605/1927742) add stop(true, true)  it is work now! Thanks!!