# jQuery addClass keeping class there

Tags: jquery

So I have some jQuery that slides down a menu, I had to do add class for hover when I am hovering over the slid down DIV I need the hover effect to stay active on the menu item.

The problem is that it just stays there even when the DIV has disappeared - I have tried to use removeClass but then it removes it as soon as I scroll onto the menu options DIV.

I have JsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/pCTXq/3/

the jQuery is below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu_item, .menu_options").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
        $(".menu_options").stop(true, true).slideDown(400);
    }, function() {
        $(".menu_options").stop(true, true).delay(10).slideUp(400);
    });

});
```

I had a look at post [jquery hover().addClass() problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358964/jquery-hover-addclass-problem) but that didn't seem to help much

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT. Just noticed also that on the JSfiddle it seems to be adding the hover class to menu_options also - this is not the case when I test the actual script in the browser

Comment: I just whipped this up, but perhaps this is what you are trying to achieve:  http://jsfiddle.net/pCTXq/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of the second parameter to `slideUp`.  When it completes, remove the class then.  Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu_item, .menu_options").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        $(".menu_options").stop(true, true).slideDown(400);
    }, function() {
        $(".menu_options").stop(true, true).delay(10).slideUp(400, function( {
            $(".menu_item, .menu_options").removeClass('hover')
        });
    });
}
```

Saved in your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/pCTXq/9/

So, basically, add the hover class on hover (or mouseenter is actually more appropriate), and don't remove it till you finish scrolling up.  You may need to tweak what this is added to (from the looks of it, just `$(".menu_item")` may do it), but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

## Edit:

[See this fiddle for updated answer](http://jsfiddle.net/pCTXq/11/)

---

You need to remove the class off hover, if I've understood your question correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu_item, .menu_options").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
        $(".menu_options").stop(true, true).slideDown(400);
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
        $(".menu_options").stop(true, true).delay(10).slideUp(400);
    });
    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I tried that but what that does is takes the class off as soon as I go into the menu_options div (the slide down one) I need it to stay there whilst I am over that div and remove when coming off

Comment: @JamesLeist You're not making sense, to be honest. What div do you want the class on, and when do you want that class removed, exactly?

Comment: So the menu_item div needs to show the hover and then when I scroll on to menu_options the hover effect needs to stay on menu_item then when I scroll off menu_options the hover needs to disappear - at the moment it stays there

Comment: thank you so much for your help but I think I have it now :-)

Comment: @JamesLeist See the edit fiddle, still not sure, is that what you want?